# Is it possible for users to see up/down votes for meta questions?

Tags: feature-request

Specifically after seeing [this](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/yearly-limitations-on-potw-submissions) post, it would be interesting to see the up/down votes as you would when looking in your own profile (reputation). Since this is meta and reflects the community a down vote is almost more important that an up vote.

The one thing though that I don't want is too have someone targeted because they down voted something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All votes are (and should be) anonymous for the reasons you mention.

Once you've earnt 1,000 (IIRC) reputation, you can click on the vote total, and then see how that is broken down by up votes vs. down votes.

Comment: Ok, so I best asking and answering more questions. I've still got a long way to go :)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that, thanks!